# Function to compare number doesn't work as expected

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

> ```
>    Col1    Col2    Col3   ......     
>     30      50      90         
>     50      50      20
> ```

I would like simply to compare row 1 and row 2 of each column in this way:

if

> DF[[i]][i] >  DF[[i]][i + 1] --> 1   (so compare row1 with row2 of each column)

if

> DF[[i]][i] <  DF[[i]][i + 1] --> -1

if

> DF[[i]][i] ==  DF[[i]][i + 1] --> 0

I tried to write the following function. Unfortunately it does not work.

> ```
>  myfunc <- function(Data){
> ```
>
> Data = df_a_freq
>            if(!is.numeric(Data)){
>           stop("argument x must be numeric")}
>             value <- list()
>       for (i in 1: length(Data)){
>       if (Data[[i]][i] > Data[[i]][i+1]){
>   value <- 1}
>   else if(Data[[i]][i] < Data[[i]][i+1]){
>   value <- -1}
>   else { 
>           value <- 0
>       }
>     }
>   return(value)
>   }

When I run the function the following error occurs:

> ```
>   Error in if (Data [[i]] [i]> Data [[i]] [i + 1]) {:
> ```
>
> missing value is required where TRUE / FALSE

I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ifelse` for example:

```
ifelse(DF[1,] > DF[2,],1,
       ifelse(DF[1,] < DF[2,],-1,0))
```

Using your data :

```
DF <- read.table(text= 'Col1    Col2    Col3  
                 30      50      90         
                 50      50      20 ',header=TRUE    )
ifelse(DF[1,] > DF[2,],1,
       ifelse(DF[1,] < DF[2,],-1,0))

 Col1 Col2 Col3
  -1    0    1
```